# Bandpass filter causing strange cutoffs in time domain

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

The original signal I have is shown in the left hand side of the image and after filtering it looks as shown in the right hand side. 
[image]
I am using a hamming window FIR filter with passband [0.05Hz to 2Hz] and 95 taps. I have used firwin from python for this purpose:

```
hamming_coeffs = firwin(95, [0.05/f_nyquist, 2.0/f_nyquist], pass_zero=False) 

hamming = np.convolve(hamming_coeffs, signal, mode='full')
```

Can someone explain why there is a sudden drop in the signal at 5 seconds and 15 seconds after filtering?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What is your sample rate?  The startup and ending filtering transients will be

```
transient_sec = (filt_len-1)/(sample_rate_hz)
```

which for this large filter (95 elements) may be substantial.   With the `mode='full'` argument to `np.convolve()` the transients will be on full display, as they are here.  With a longer time series their influence will not be as obvious.

The transients can be hidden by using the `mode='valid'` option to `np.convolve()`.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your time axis is incorrectly labeled.

The result of a full convolution is longer than the original signal, so the second graph should show 20 units plus some amount of filter transient time before and after your initial signal, maybe from -10.0 to 30.0 seconds.  Your filtered signal is the shrunken portion in the middle.